# What is the easiest way to solve SVD numerically?

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, svd

I want to solve Singular Valude Decomposition(SVD)

$$A = USV^T$$

I have been using the QR-method before, but it takes lot of time and is very slow. Is there any easier method to use? Is it easy to find the eigenvalues of a big matrix?

What method do you recommend to solve SVD?

I going to implement a SVD solver in C-programming langugage for embedded systems, so MATLAB is no use here for me.

Comment: I'd use gsl here, or maybe gsl's code.

Comment: @kimchilover Yes...but...I don't know how GNU Scientific Library handles malloc. Malloc can be used in embedded systems, but only at the beginning. So I don't trust GSL. Also GSL is huge and takes up all the memory.

Comment: I meant, can you steal the 1500 or so lines of svd code from gsl, and write your own low level calls to avoid malloc?

Comment: 1500 lines of math-c-code? No, that would be impossible to read.

Comment: Are you reducing your matrix to bidiagonal form as a preprocessing step for computing the singular values?

Comment: I don't know. I just try to find svd as easy as possible.

Comment: Perhaps QR method is the best?

Comment: Why reinvent a wheel and not use [clapack](https://www.netlib.org/clapack/)? No malloc in there. All matrices and workspace are passed as arguments and can (actually have to) be preallocated.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Wow! I haven't seen that. Do you think c-laplack will fit embedded systems?

Comment: I don't know what does that entail but roughly: C, no "random" mallocs. If that is the case, yes, it fits.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Thank you! I will start using CLapack. Can I use the BLAS-library that already contains in the Clapack library, or do I need to find a BLAS-library that fits the target CPU e.g ARM?

Comment: There's a "generic" BLAS library already included.

Comment: Good! I hope it will fit STM32. @AlgebraicPavel